# Read h5 files through a NAS

Tags: python, pandas, h5py, nas

I'm reading h5 files from remote, previously it was on a server but more recently I had to store some on a NAS device. When I'm trying to read the ones on the NAS, for some of them I have the following error:

```
HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Dio.c", line 199, in H5Dread
    can't read data
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Dio.c", line 603, in H5D__read
    can't read data
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Dcontig.c", line 621, in H5D__contig_read
    contiguous read failed
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Dselect.c", line 283, in H5D__select_read
    read error
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Dselect.c", line 218, in H5D__select_io
    read error
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Dcontig.c", line 956, in H5D__contig_readvv
    can't perform vectorized sieve buffer read
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5VM.c", line 1500, in H5VM_opvv
    can't perform operation
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Dcontig.c", line 753, in H5D__contig_readvv_sieve_cb
    block read failed
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Fio.c", line 118, in H5F_block_read
    read through page buffer failed
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5PB.c", line 732, in H5PB_read
    read through metadata accumulator failed
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5Faccum.c", line 260, in H5F__accum_read
    driver read request failed
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5FDint.c", line 205, in H5FD_read
    driver read request failed
  File "C:\ci\hdf5_1593121603621\work\src\H5FDsec2.c", line 725, in H5FD_sec2_read
    file read failed: time = Tue May 10 11:37:06 2022
, filename = 'Y:/myFolder\myFile.h5', file descriptor = 4, errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', buf = 0000020F03F14040, total read size = 16560000, bytes this sub-read = 16560000, bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 480252764

End of HDF5 error back trace

Problems reading the array data.
```

I don't really understand the error, it always happend for the same files, but I can open the file and read the data myself with HDFView. If I put it on the server I can read it without problem with the same lines of code (path is correct for both):

```
hdf5store = pd.HDFStore(myPath[fich])
        
datacopy = hdf5store['my_data']
```

Btw the error occurs at this 2nd line of code. Right now I don't have access to the server and can't copy the file on local because I don't have enough space. If anyone know how to correct this so I could continue to work through the NAS ?

Comment: Is the data set flat or chunked? With or without compression? If you run ```h5repack input.h5 output.h5``` and then try to read the output, does it work? I'm asking because I've had more than enough issues where checksum errors due to file corruption on NASes occurred and not every application properly reported that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was not aware of those parameters I'm a beginner. As I didn't mention anything when I create the file I'm guessing it's flat without compression? code to create the file: "hdf5store = pd.HDFStore(myPath+ filename + '.h5'). hdf5store['my_data'] = df". df being my dataframe.

I did not succeed to use h5repack (which I did not know before) like u indicate me to. It says "invalid syntax", do I need to import something ?

Comment: h5repack is a commandline application. It looks like you tried running it in python. You can inspect the file further with ```h5ls -rv file.h5```. Maybe post the output

Comment: Ar you using `pandas` or `h5py`? Code has `pandas` functions, but post is tagged with `h5py`. (FYI, I added `pandas` tag.)

Comment: Oh ok but commands dont seems to work, "h5ls -rv file.h5" (don't know how to put code in comment like you) result in "h5repack: unknown option "r". Ofc I changes "file" to my actual file.

I'm using pandas I though I would need h5py aswell but not for the code displayed here yes, my bad thanks for editing